# How to call ajax function after clicking print button in print window using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to call ajax function after clicking print button from print window using jquery?

In my web page I have printCertificate button. When I click this button, print window appear and the printing is successful.
I want to update something in database table after printing that is only if I click button OK in print window. In short I want to call another function  Anyone help me to incorporate this in jquery please.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some code for context and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onafterprint = function(e){
    console.log('Print Dialog Closed..');
};
```

Comment: Thank you Every Screamer for your answer. Would you please elaborate how to detect if button print or cancel is clicked?

Comment: @NgawangZepa im not sure, but i would say you cant... you cant access chrome or other browser default window... only solution that i can offer is to make your own print window... and program that...